# Why VS tell me that change decimal number for a method to hex or binary

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, mapping

i have a question about the helper in VS 2017.

I write this code in a ClassMap: `Map(x => x.Meta).Length(length: 1000).Not.Nullable();`

and then the VS tell me that change number of Length to hex or binary like this`Map(x => x.Meta).Length(length: 0b1111101000).Not.Nullable();` or like this`Map(x => x.Meta).Length(length: 0x3E8).Not.Nullable();`

my question is: why the VS helper show me this message?

[this is picture of the helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhhJG.png)

Comment: VS just suggest you and it is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not saying *to* change the format to hex or binary. This isn't a warning or hint and shouldn't show up at all unless you specifically click the lightbulb when the focus is on a number.

It's merely provided as an option so that *if* you want to change the format to hex or binary, you don't need to do the calculation yourself.